# Change Default Page Layout for Pages in Enterprise Wiki Library - 2010

Tags: wiki, page-layout

I have a Site called Workspaces, created with the Enterprise Wiki Template, and am hosting two Wiki Libraries within the site. Whenever a user views an individual Wiki Page, regardless of the Wiki Library, I would like to have a zone on the right hand side that would allow for web parts or ASCX controls.

Is there a way to change the page layout just for viewing Wiki Library pages? If so, how, and would I need to attach this setting to each page, each library, on the Wiki Library type itself, etc.?

I am happy to code whatever is needed, but just need a push in the right direction.

Rough image of desired result is provided:
http://img268.imageshack.us/i/sharepointwikilibrarypa.png/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise wiki's are basically Publishing pages so the exact same techniques you use to create a publishing page layout can be used. You can create a new aspx layout and bind it to the content type and library.